# Compulsary permission check and still location = null

Tags: android, android-studio, locationmanager

I am not able to understand the forced need of permission check in my code.

Moreover, even after doing that, the location is null.

This is the code of my onCreate method:
Please help!!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if(provider.equals(null)){
        Log.i("provdier","prob");
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }


    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        Log.i("location info", "achieved");
        textView.setText("Achieved");
    } else {
        Log.i("location info", "failed");
        textView.setText("Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: first understand while its compulsory to add permission check in this code. This will lead you to resolve your issue. Hint:- android version more than 23 required to permission check. and ask for permissions at run time. This is only happen your build version is 23 or higher

Comment: I have added the permissions but I still get Location as null. Have you found a solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 private Location getLastKnownLocation() {

       LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;

        for (String provider : providers) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return TODO;
            }
            Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return bestLocation;


    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still null